# Pandas - Merging Different Sized DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue merging two frames with a different amount of rows. The first dataframe has 5K rows, and the second dataframe has 20K rows. There is a column "id" in both frames, and all 5K "id" values will occur in the frame with 20K rows.

first frame "df"

```
     A    B    id    A_1    B_1
0    1    1    1     0.5    0.5
1    3    2    2     0.2    0.4
2    3    4    3     0.8    0.9
```

second frame "df_2"

```
     A    B    id    
0    1    1    1    
1    3    2    2    
2    3    4    3    
3    1    2    4    
4    3    1    5
```

Hopeful output frame "df_out"

```
     A    B    id    A_1    B_1
0    1    1    1     0.5    0.5
1    3    2    2     0.2    0.4
2    3    4    3     0.8    0.9
3    1    2    4     na     na
4    3    1    5     na     na
```

My attempts to merge on 'id' have left me with only the 5k rows. The operation I am seeking is to preserve all the rows of the large dataframe, and stick Nan values for the data that does not exist in the large frame.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `how='outer'` option of `pd.merge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify `how=outer` to [`df.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) so that you use the union of both DataFrames.

```
>>> df.merge(df_2, how='outer')
     A  A_1    B  B_1   id
0  1.0  0.5  1.0  0.5  1.0
1  3.0  0.2  2.0  0.4  2.0
2  3.0  0.8  4.0  0.9  3.0
3  1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  4.0
4  3.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  5.0
```

Comment: @JeffSaltfist Glad I could help!

Comment: quick question, does the 'outer' argument signify the last column in the frame?

Comment: @JeffSaltfist It specifies that the union of keys from both DataFrames should be used to merge, as opposed to the intersection or the entirety of one or the other (see the docs I linked).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve the issue with your code and by also including left_index=False and right_index=False in the code.